# Breaking multiple block types with one tool

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a lumber tycoon in minecraft, and I have a command by the press of a button to take money from the player and give the product with the "privilege" to break logs, but it seems to only break oak logs.

The command I am using is: `/give @p wooden_axe 1 0 ("minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["log"]}}`

How can I make it break all other types of log too?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pick all of the other wood types: "log" defaults to "oak_log", since oak was the first tree type in the game.

`/give @p wooden_axe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["oak_log","spruce_log","birch_log","jungle_log","acacia_log","dark_oak_log"]}}` should work.

Comment: Can you make sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: @zerealsendy4 Does it break all blocks instead of just logs?

Comment: No the code just straight up doesn't work

Comment: @zerealsendy4 I made a typo. Whoops. Should work now.

Comment: So whats the new command?

Comment: Or is that the code already?

Comment: @zerealsendy4 Sorry for delay: I edited the answer so it should now work. I'll also post it in comments: `/give @p wooden_axe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["oak_log","spruce_log","birch_log","jungle_log","acacia_log","dark_oak_log"]}}`

Comment: now it just says: "unknown command: please check that the command exists and that you have permission to use it"

Comment: @zerealsendy4 Do you have cheats enabled? If not, you can’t use it.

Comment: No yeah I do have cheats on